# When does an object qualify as a DTO?

Tags: jvm, design-patterns, dto

**DTO (Data Transfer Objects)** are objects used to transfer information  between multiple subsystems of an application, often separated  by either a network or a process boundary. This is my understanding.

However, from  Java perspective, do the subsystems/modules *have to be on different JVM instances* for the objects they use between them to qualify as DTOs? (I believe that a significant demarcation in architecture in terms of modularity and functionality between the subsystems would be sufficient.) What say?

Also, considering the objects exchanged by multiple modules in *the SAME layer/tier* of an architecture, don't these objects qualify as DTOs? Is a tier separation mandatory?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Nagendra U M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because transferring objects between tiers requires some kind of serialization it is considered a DTO. Transferring objects between layers is generally done through the use of domain entities thus not requiring serialization.

So your DTOs generally do not have behavior only properties to hold data.

A little note: DTOs are often mistaken for anemic objects when you have entities with no behavior, only data. Or poltergeist objects when objects are only used to transport data in and out of methods or classes and then disappear.

As an example sometimes your data persistence mechanism requires you to implement or inherit interfaces or classes that you do not want to couple into your domain layer, so you create objects that inherit or implement the interface/class and transfer data to those classes for persistence.

```
class Person{
public string Name {get;set;}
public int Age {get;set;}

public void Validate(){}
public void DoSomething(){}
}



public class PersonDTO : TableServiceContext
{
public const string ContactTableName = "PersonTable"

public string Name {get;set;}
public int Age {get;set;}

}
```

And you would generaly have a class to assemble and disassemble these objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Fine. I agree that DTOs primarily have only data, and little or no behavior. 

But, is serialization mandatory for a DTO to be called as a DTO? As long as we are able to demarcate distinctively between subsystems and establish a contract to exchange data between them through non-serializable objects (assuming the subsystems share the same JVM), can't we still call the objects as DTOs? (atleast in principle)??

The second question regarding objects moving across and within architectural tiers is still unanswered. 

Regards,
Nagendra U M

Comment: Fowler states that DTOs are for reducing remote calls and serializing all data at once http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html. Although today I think we use it for more than that, such as my example which the main focus isn't to reduce expensive calls but to not couple my domain models to my data persistence mechanism in order to make a remote transport. As for the architecture question, I don't believe they are DTOs because those objects are not subject to remote transport which is the purpose of a DTO.